# How to move wordpress admin bar menu to my theme title bar

Tags: php, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I want to move wordpress admin bar menu to my theme title bar menus pls help i dont know php.[Check this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHsSd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible.. wordpress admin bar will be removed when user logout from wordpress admin.. so you can write your own codes to get the user details.. gud luck

Comment: i'm asking for logged in scenario.